# Variadic argument recursion without passing in instances of arguments

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, variadic-templates, variadic

For some reason I can't seem to get this operation to work with C++11.

```
template<typename T>
int value(){ return 1;}


template<typename T1>
constexpr int SumCpp11(){
  return value<T1>();
}

template<typename T1, typename... T>
constexpr int SumCpp11(){
  return value<T1>() + SumCpp11<T...>();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

   return  SumCpp11<int, int, double, double>();
   
}
```

The compiler happily unwinds the recursion until the terminal case, and then complains about ambiguous declarations.   I have reworked this repeatedly.  I can't use the initializer list trick because I need to stay in C++11 and this needs to be a constexpr because this final value is being used as a template parameter in another part of the code.

```
clang++ --std=c++11 tailVar.cpp 
tailVar.cpp:13:24: error: call to 'SumCpp11' is ambiguous
  return value<T1>() + SumCpp11<T...>();
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
tailVar.cpp:13:24: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'SumCpp11<double, double>' requested here
tailVar.cpp:13:24: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'SumCpp11<int, double, double>' requested here
tailVar.cpp:20:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'SumCpp11<int, int, double, double>' requested
      here
   return  SumCpp11<int, int, double, double>();
           ^
tailVar.cpp:7:15: note: candidate function [with T1 = double]
constexpr int SumCpp11(){
              ^
tailVar.cpp:12:15: note: candidate function [with T1 = double, T = <>]
constexpr int SumCpp11(){
              ^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message says, when you reach the base case, i.e. with 1 template parameter, the compiler can't choose between the overloads of `SumCpp11`. The first overload says it has 1 parameter, and the second overload says it has 1 or more parameters. The rules for overloading don't allow for the first one to be chosen, as you intended.

A simple fix would be to make the second overload take 2 or more template parameters. This way when you have 2 or more parameters, the second overload is chosen, and when you have 1 parameter, there is no ambiguity and the first overload is chosen.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename... T>
constexpr int SumCpp11(){
  return value<T1>() + SumCpp11<T2, T...>();
                                //  ^^^^ when T... is empty, 
                                // the first overload is chosen
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zd1cKa).

Comment: I had tried the two argument idea but as value<T1>()+value<T2>+SumCpp11<T...> but ended up stalling one level of recursion earlier.  Your approach does work.  thanks!

Comment: I was just about to post the same answer, but you beat me to it. Here is a [demo](https://ideone.com/WH6HSC).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the demo; I added it to the answer. I prefer godbolt so I used that instead :)

Comment: @Meta.x.gdb Yes, you're on the right track, but as you found, you run into the same issue if you write the implementation that way. The instantiation of `SumCpp11` needs to be able to call the right overload, and passing it only `T...` doesn't let it do that.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest an alternative way to solve the problem: rewrite the `SumCpp11()` functions as follows

```
template <int = 0>
constexpr int SumCpp11 ()
 { return 0; }

template<typename T1, typename... T>
constexpr int SumCpp11()
 { return value<T1>() + SumCpp11<T...>(); }
```

I mean... the ground case become the call with an empty `T...` variadic list. In that case, the recursive call

```
SumCpp11<T...>()
```

become

```
SumCpp11<>()
```

that, thanks to the default template value (zero) for the integer template parameter, matches

```
SumCpp11<0>()
```

so the ground case.

Comment: That works as well!   any default empty case seems to work...

Comment: @Meta.x.gdb - the trick is that the ground case should accept something different from a type (so a value or a template-template) with a default. Obviously you can substitute `int = 0` with `int = 1`, `long = 0`, `template <typename...> class = std::tuple`... as you prefer. But doesn't works with a typename, so no `typename = void`.

Comment: I never figured "0" matches the empty parameter pack expansion.   I would have to watch out for someone calling the function with a literal "0" though, but that is not what happens in my specific case